# CMD dir command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm using dir to retrive all directories from specified path but I'm getting directories paths from two locations.

```
dir "C:\ssis" /b /s /ad *.* | sort >c:\ssis\task4\content.txt
```

And result is

[image]

I want to get only marked (yellow) lines. Not directories from place where I open CMD

Thanks :)
PM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `*.*`:

```
dir "C:\ssis" /b /s /ad | sort >c:\ssis\task4\content.txt
```

Because you specify the directory where you want to list the files earlier `"C:\ssis"` so `*.*` will also list files in actual directory.